# javascript regex check character before match but don't include it in result

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to implement the two following rules in a single regex:

If a number is preceeded by :

- a word character or a @ character ; then do not match anything
- anything else ; then match the number **but do not include the preceeding character** in the result

I tried: `[^@\d,\w]\d+` and `(?:[^@\d,\w])\d+`

Which solve the first rule, but fail to solve the second one, as it includes the operator in the result.

I understand why it doesn't work as intended ; the `[^@\d\w]` part explicitly says to not match numbers preceeded by a @ or a word character, so it implicitly says to include anything else in the result. Problem is I still have no idea how to solve this.

**Is there any way to implement the two rules in a single regex ?**

Input string:

```
@121 //do not match
+39  //match but don't include the + sign in result
s21  //do not match
89   //match
(98  //match but don't include the ( in result
/4   //match but don't include the / operator in result
```

Expected result:

```
39 //operator removed
89  
98 //( removed
4  //operator removed
```

Comment: when you say "in the result", could it be implemented as a capturing group or is it required that it should be the whole match? because capturing the numbers would easily solve this: `[^@\d,\w](\d+)` would give you the char in the whole match, but only the numbers in the capture

Comment: Do you want to replace something?

Comment: *the [^@\d\w] part explicitly says to not match numbers preceeded by a @ or a word character...* no it says any number of characters that are not included in character set. Order is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Capture the result you're seeking as the snippet below suggests.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/02jltm/1)

```
^[^@\w]?(\d+)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^@\w]?` Optionally match any character except `@` or a word character
- `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 1

```js
var a = ["@121", "+39", "s21", "89", "(98", "/4"]
var r = /^[^@\w]?(\d+)/

a.forEach(function(s){
  var m = s.match(r)
  if(m != null) console.log(m[1])
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I was actually hoping for a regex-only solution as I won't be able to split my string like you did without refactoring a fair portion of code. I will do it if I have no other choice, but is there really no other way to get the result directly from regex without using capture groups to access the desired result ?

Comment: @Hal_9100 JavaScript regex only supports lookbehinds in Chrome 62+ at the moment (as MinusFour's answer shows), so the only way to do this right now is using capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a finished proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) for negative lookbehind which I think it's what you are looking for:

```js
let arr =
['@121', //do not match
'+39', //match but don't include the + sign in result
's21',  //do not match
'89',   //match
'(98',  //match but don't include the ( in result
'/4'   //match but don't include the / operator in result
];

console.log(arr.map(v => v.match(/(?<![@\w])\d+/)));
```

**It's a bleeding edge feature however (works on chromium 62+ i think).**

Comment: I think last line should come bold.

Comment: Thank you! this proposal would definitely be what I'm looking for if it had already a wider support. Unfortunately I will have to search another solution until then